# There are no link/unlink buttons related to Smart Action in the Assistant Directory

Tags: google-smart-home

There are no "Link"/"Unlink" buttons (for linking/unlinking account) related to Smart Action in the Assistant Directory (https://assistant.google.com/ -> explore actions). They appear from time to time, but the behavior looks unstable.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLZNX.png)

Could you please clarify at what moments each of these buttons should appear?

How this issue could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The option to link a 3rd party account with Google Assistant is only available if the Action's development team has [enabled account linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-oauth).